# Yii2: Use popover in form validation messages

Tags: javascript, validation, yii2, active-form

I'm looking to create custom validation messages on my activeforms in Yii2 for the client side validation. The goal i want to achieve is to get a bootstrap popover on the side of the form field with the validation error message of that field, e.g. password too short or password does not meet the requirements. These messages change dynamicaly based on the given input and validation rules.

I've been looking at using the clientValidateAttribute and create javascripts for the fields, this is working but i'm missing out on setting the proper validation messages coming from the model validation.

This is a simple example to create a popover based on some conditions in the clientValidateAttribute.

```
return <<<JS
    var def = $.Deferred();

    if (attribute.name == "email" && value !== "") {
        $( ".login-pop" ).popover("show");
    } else {
        $( ".login-pop" ).popover("destroy");
    }

    deferred.push(def);
JS;
```

This will show an popover on the .login-pop class field when the attribute is email and its empty. I've been looking to use the messages array, but it looks like it's only set once.

Perhaps i'm mislead with the validation and there might be easier or better solutions to achieve this goal and be able to validate per field, return the proper messages to be used in a javascript tool.

Thank you.